# Adding 2nd DC to the domain from a different subnet over VPN. -UPDATE:  Not working!

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, domain-controller

I'm in the process of adding a second DC to our domain and just want to make sure I have all the steps right before proceeding.

Info:

DC1 is 2008 R2 Standard.

DC2 is 2008 R2 Standard. //Edit:  DC2 is 2008 Standard.

Network1 is 192.168.39.x/24

Network2 is 10.0.0.x/24

VPN is Sonicwall.

The 2 DC's will be at two different sites, but the networks are connected by hardware VPN. (Sonicwall).  The main DC server will be on the 192.168.39.0/24 network.  The 2nd DC will be on 10.0.0.0/24.

Here are the steps I plan to take; please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Part 1:

AD Sites and Services on DC1, create a new site and subnet for DC2. (Or should I create a new one for *both?*)

(Can I use the default IPSiteLink and not change anything in there other than refresh timer?)

Part 2:

Point the DNS of DC2 to DC1.  Run /forestprep and /domainprep (on both, or just DC1?).

Dcpromo and select "Additional Domain Controller for Existing Domain".  Then continue with normal steps with default locations for databases.

EDIT:  Didn't realize this was like reddit and required two skipped lines to skip one :P

EDIT 2:  When DCPromo-ing DC2, do I need to have "Append primary and connection specific DNS" and "Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix" checked?

EDIT 3:  I started the process of joining the domain when I came across the error, "The functional level of the domain or forest is incompatible with this operating system."
"The version of the OS is incompatible with the current domain functional level"

Solved: I had to downgrade the functional level of the domain AND the forest following these steps + the small change in syntax provided by the user in comments below.

http://www.fixkar.com/articles/kb/1151/

Thanks all for help.

Comment: EDIT 2: When DCPromo-ing DC2, do I need to have "Append primary and connection specific DNS" and "Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix" checked?

Comment: Comment to Edit 2: That's the default setting so leave it as it is with the caveat that you should not have any connection specific suffixes.

Comment: Please check my 3rd edit. I am not able to join the domain because the functional level is "R2", and my DC2 is only 2008 Standard. I read somewhere that I can lower the functional level as long as AD recycle bin (I think that's what it's called) isn't enabled. Help! – EagerToLearn 6 mins ago

Comment: I had to downgrade the functional level of the domain AND the forest following these steps: http://www.fixkar.com/articles/kb/1151/ Thanks all for help.

Comment: Glad to help and glad you got everything working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should have ADS&S configured for all sites/subnets, even when you have only one. No need to change the replication settings unless you have specific needs/limitations.
2. No need to run /forestprep or /domainprep.

Comment: +1.  One extra note on the IP site link; if you have any kind of decent bandwidth between the sites, consider setting the `options` attribute on your IP Site Link to `0x1`.  This'll put it in `USE_NOTIFY` mode, ignoring the replication schedule and replicating changes immediately.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused by the first part of your answer.  Are you saying I shouldn't use the default site, and should create two new sites?  Thanks, -Will

Comment: Unfortunately the bandwidth is pretty bad in one of the locations. (T1 for an office of 30 people).

Comment: Another note: Make sure you understand the difference between the replication schedule and the replication availability.

Comment: @user85958: No, I'm saying you should add a subnet to the default site and set up a new site/subnet for the new site. Every site (even if you have only one) should have a corresponding subnet configured for it.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense.  --Ok I'll read up on the difference between the two.  I'm assuming "availability" is just when it's "allowed" to replicate.  Maybe I'll set it to early in the morning and late at night.  Roughly how much bandwidth does a replication/sync take?  Assuming there are little-to-no changes?

Comment: @user85958: You got it. The default inter-site replication is every 180 minutes (schedule), 24x7 (availability). You can adjust the schedule or availability as needed based on the quality/availability of the link and the amount of replication traffic you expect to have. Note that the terms schedule and availability get mixed up a bit in my opinion. The interval between replications is the schedule and the hours wherein replication can occur is the availability. You can measure the replication traffic with the help of this article: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742457.aspx#ECAA.

Comment: Please check my 3rd edit.  I am not able to join the domain because the functional level is "R2", and my DC2 is only 2008 Standard.  I read somewhere that I can lower the functional level as long as AD recycle bin (I think that's what it's called) isn't enabled.  Help!